# How to add values to the existing rows after adding new columns using ALT and ADD

Tags: mysql

This is my code

```
CREATE TABLE youtube
(
    name varchar(25),
    Likes int(16),
    dislikes int(16)
);

INSERT INTO YOUTUBE (NAME, LIKES, DISLIKES)
VALUES
('mysql','23','21'),
('data structure','56','36'),
('computernetworks','45','36'),
('OS','23','49');
```

Now I'm adding one more columns to the existing table

```
ALTER TABLE youtube
    ADD views varchar(25);

INSERT INTO youtube(views)
VALUES 
('100'),
('153'),
('126'),
('326'),
('526');
```

After this I'm getting output as:

[image]

You can see in above image that VIEWS is created with new row with null data where as I want to add this VIEWS to the corresponding SUBJECTS rows not as it is shown in output image.

Answer (score 1):

First,I would suggest you using `UPDATE` to do it.

For your question,you can try with **[INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-or-update-on-duplicate-key-update/)**.

```
INSERT INTO YOUTUBE (name, likes,dislikes,views)
    VALUES
  ('mysql','23','21','100'),
  ('data structure','56','36','153'),
  ('computernetworks','45','36','126'),
  ('OS','23','49','326')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    name = name,
    likes = likes,
    dislike = dislikes
```

To archive this, you also need to add a unique index to some column(such as `name` in your code) or add primary key to your table.

Comment: for this i've to re-write the code for creating table and include VIEW in that .but don't want to do this I want to use the same existing table and want to add VIEW column. can i do this with UPDATE ? if yes let me know how

Comment: @Ashish If using `update`,then I think you can only update one by one,each time only update one row

Comment: okay.Let me try with **INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.** as you said.